# how to set animation curve when using keyframe animation in ios?

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, core-animation

How to set animation curve when using UIView's keyframe animation :

```
animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

Whatever I do in the animation block seems to be linear (unless I use the `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubic` option but this isn't what I want).

I'd like to have an ease out curve on the animation like the `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` option when using regular animation :

```
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using keyframes, you have to define the curve on your own.. if you add linear keyframes, you have a linear animation. If you add non-linear keyframes, you will have a non-linear animation.

The `frameStartTime` is your friend here... it will always be linear between keyframes (or paced / cubic / cubic paced, like defined in the `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationMode`)

```
UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear     = 0 << 9,
UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeDiscrete   = 1 << 9,
UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModePaced      = 2 << 9,
UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubic      = 3 << 9,
UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubicPaced = 4 << 9
```

To calculate correct timing values, you could use this as a reference:
[RBBEasingFunction](https://github.com/robb/RBBAnimation/blob/master/RBBAnimation/RBBEasingFunction.m)

E.g. `EaseInOutQuad` like this (where t is the relative time within the animation):

```
if (t < 0.5) {
    return 2 * t * t;
} else {
    return -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

**Swift 2.0** will not allow casting of `UIViewAnimationOptions` as `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions`. It will also not allow `|`ing them together.

However, there is an initializer for `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions` that takes a `rawValue`. So, the following code works to put `UIViewAnimationOptions` into `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions`:

```
let animationOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = .CurveEaseOut
let keyframeAnimationOptions: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)
```

Then I can pass `keyframeAnimationOptions`  to `animateKeyframesWithDuration` and everything works great.

For Swift 4:

```
let animationOptions = AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut
let options = KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)
```

Comment: How can I increase the `.CurveEaseOut` effect? Thanks, nice answer!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in swift3 and higher. The animation still appears linear. Has anyone found a solution that works in swift4?

Answer (score 13):

Actually, you can use the same curve flags that you use for animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:. Just "binary or" them in with the other options in your call to animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

The documentation is confusing, but it does work.

The curve values you can use are:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut = 0 << 16,
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn    = 1 << 16,
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut   = 2 << 16,
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear    = 3 << 16,
```

The default animation curve you get is 0, or ease-in, ease-out.

Comment: Awesome! works fine. Very weird this isn't in the documentation, specially since they have non-linear as default...

Comment: Well, after trying all the KeyFrameOptions I went back to this which is what I had to begin with. It gives a warning but works perfectly :)

Comment: This won't work with Swift because everything is strongly typed!

Comment: @fatuhoku, you should be able to overcome that with typecasting

Comment: In Swift 4 for `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` it'd be: `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: (3 << 16))`

Answer (score 11):

Here's a nice and clean Swift solution I came up with:

```
extension UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions {

    init(animationOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions) {
        rawValue = animationOptions.rawValue
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(animationOptions: .CurveEaseOut)
```

Comment: Swift 5: self.init(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @eskimwier did not work for me when trying to set the curve to **`linear`** for `animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)`. This was in Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1.

My animation appeared to be defaulting to `easeInOut` (slow start up, faster in the middle, slow at the end). Did Apple change the default curve?

Anyhow, I wanted a linear curve, and tried the approach suggested above to use `UIViewAnimationOptions` with keyframe animations:

```
let animationOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = .curveLinear
var keyframeAnimationOptions: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)

UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [keyframeAnimationOptions], animations: {
    //... animations here ...
}, completion: nil)
```

This had no effect. The only thing that worked for me was to do this before calling animateKeyframes:

```
UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.linear)
```

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions. The first option (with the `keyframeAnimationOptions` was the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to set the animation curve for the keyframe animation is to wrap the keyframe animation inside the UIViewPropertyAnimator object:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .linear) {

    // withDuration: 0 means inherited duration from UIViewPropertyAnimator
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration:0.5) {
            // modify view's properties
        }

        // more keyframes
    })
}

animator.startAnimation()
```