# iOS: springWithDamping like animation for KeyFrame animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uianimation

I had the following custom transition using `UIView.animateWithDuration(...usingSpringWithDamping:...)` which worked perfectly.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext),
    delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0,
    options: nil, animations: {() in
    // ...
}, completion: {(Bool) in
    // ...
})
```

But then I had to extend my custom transition with `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` in order to have an interactive transition where the user can swipe down the modal view again.

Therefore I needed keyframes for the animation in order that the `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` works properly.

So I changed the animation function to use `UIView.animateWithKeyframes...`.

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext),
    delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeCubic,
    animations: {() in
    // ...
}, completion: {(Bool) in
    // ...
})
```

My problem now: I lost the spring animation.

I've checked several links, one of the most promising was:

- [Stackoverflow #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638956/how-to-set-animation-curve-when-using-keyframe-animation-in-ios)

... but with `.addKeyframes...` method I cannot specify a completion block that I need.

Any suggestions? :-/

Comment: did you look at  https://github.com/felixjendrusch/Marionette   ?

Comment: as an aside, checkout this post on spring animations https://medium.com/@flyosity/your-spring-animations-are-bad-and-it-s-probably-apple-s-fault-784932e51733