# How do I set animation curves for UIView keyframe animations (`func UIView.animateKeyframes()`)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, keyframe

UIView keyframe animations let you create view animations that proceed through a series of steps. The function `animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)` has an options parameter of type `UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions`. I would expect that to let me select an overall timing curve to apply to the combined set of animations. It appears to apply a default animation curve of ease-in,ease-out, and does not seem to allow you to specify timing curves like the `UIView.animate()` family of methods do.  What if I want linear timing, just ease-in, or just ease-out?

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, the animation options for the `UIView.animate()` methods (of type `UIView.AnimationOptions`) work if you can figure out how to pass them to `animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)`. Unfortunately, there are not existing constants for timing curves like linear, ease-in, or ease-out. [**This SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34859215/205185) shows how to "force" the values from a `UIView.AnimationOptions` constant into a `UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions` OptionSet:

```
extension UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions {

    init(animationOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions) {
        rawValue = animationOptions.rawValue
    }

}
```

I took that a step further, and defined constants for the different timing functions. (I don't know why Apple doesn't define these. It seems absurd, but there you are.)

My extension to `UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions` looks like this:

```
extension UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions {
    static var curveLinear: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions =
        UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue:UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear.rawValue)

    static var curveEaseInOut: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions =
        UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue:UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue)

    static var curveEaseIn: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions =
        UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue:UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn.rawValue)

    static var curveEaseOut: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions =
        UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue:UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut.rawValue)

    init(animationOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions) {
        self.init(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)
    }
}
```

With that extension, you can use the timing curve values just like you would in a call to the `UIView.animate()` method:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear]) {
    // Your animation keyframe steps here
}
```

Some of the other flags defined in UIView.AnimationOptions might also be valid for `UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions`. You could use the method that lets you map `UIView.AnimationOptions`  to `UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions`, or it would be trivial to add additional flags to `UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions` the same way I added the timing curve flags.

---

### Edit:

I got curious about the flags in the options to `UIView.animate()` and `animateKeyframes()` matched up. I wrote some code to log all of the values for both OptionSets, and this is what I got:

```
KeyframeAnimationOptions:
option value 0x00000001 = layoutSubviews
option value 0x00000002 = allowUserInteraction
option value 0x00000004 = beginFromCurrentState
option value 0x00000008 = repeat
option value 0x00000010 = autoreverse
option value 0x00000020 = overrideInheritedDuration
option value 0x00000200 = overrideInheritedOptions

option value 0x00000000 = calculationModeLinear
option value 0x00000400 = calculationModeDiscrete
option value 0x00000800 = calculationModePaced
option value 0x00000C00 = calculationModeCubic
option value 0x00001000 = calculationModeCubicPaced

UIView.AnimationOptions:
option value 0x00000001 = layoutSubviews
option value 0x00000002 = allowUserInteraction
option value 0x00000004 = beginFromCurrentState
option value 0x00000008 = repeat
option value 0x00000010 = autoreverse
option value 0x00000020 = overrideInheritedDuration
option value 0x00000200 = overrideInheritedOptions

option value 0x00000040 = overrideInheritedCurve
option value 0x00000080 = allowAnimatedContent
option value 0x00000100 = showHideTransitionViews
option value 0x00000000 = curveEaseInOut
option value 0x00010000 = curveEaseIn
option value 0x00020000 = curveEaseOut
option value 0x00030000 = curveLinear
option value 0x00100000 = transitionFlipFromLeft
option value 0x00200000 = transitionFlipFromRight
option value 0x00300000 = transitionCurlUp
option value 0x00400000 = transitionCurlDown
option value 0x00500000 = transitionCrossDissolve
option value 0x00600000 = transitionFlipFromTop
option value 0x00700000 = transitionFlipFromBottom
option value 0x03000000 = preferredFramesPerSecond60
option value 0x07000000 = preferredFramesPerSecond30
```

The first 7 flags in both sets have the same names and the same values. The 0 value for `KeyframeAnimationOptions` is `calculationModeLinear` and it's `curveEaseInOut` for UIView.AnimationOptions. It results in ease-in/ease-out timing for both keyframe and "regular" UIView animation.

All the other constants have values that are unique in both OptionSets, suggesting some of the other `UIView.AnimationOptions` might work for keyframe animation. I've only tested the timing curve values though, and those all work as expected.

### Edit #2:

It isn't immediately obvious how the keyframe animation flags (like calculationModeLinear , calculationModeCubic, and calculationModeCubicPaced) and the View animation flags (like curveLinear, curveEaseInOut, etc.) would interact, since the keyframe animation flags also related to animation timing. I wrote a test application to see how they do. It turns out that the UIView.AnimationOptions timing curve flags affect the overall timing of the entire keyframe animation. (The way the overall keyframe animation starts and stops.)

You can download the sample project from github [**here**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeAnimations.git).

It's a little hard to see ease-in/ease-out UIView animation timing combined with one of the cubic keyframe animation options. It's easier to see the ease-in/ease-out with keyframe calculationModeLinear mode.

Below is a video of that combo:

[image]

(Note how the cyan square coasts to a stop in the lower-right corner of the animation rectangle before returning to it's starting point.)

Comment: This is pretty awesome stuff, thanks for posting this here. It's incredibly helpful!